# Symbol's size huge in the layer tree legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

When I use `Type of symbol -> Generator of Geometry` of a vector layer that the symbol has a huge size in the layer tree legend of a QGIS projet.

I use this formula `wedge_buffer($geometry, "fyd" , "fov" , 0.00007)`, it displays well into the canvas, but it is very big into the layer tree legend.

I get the same issue with both QGIS 3.4 and 3.10, the CRS is WGS 84

Is there a way to avoid this display issue or should I forget about using `wedge_buffer`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue; the legend doesn't always display custom or complicated symbology in a useful way. Here's a workaround:

Duplicate the layer (right click > duplicate layer) - this doesn't duplicate the source data, it only creates a second link to the same source data. Give the duplicate a smaller symbology that looks like the wedge buffer (eg use a point symbol type with a quarter-circle marker). Then collapse the original layer in the legend so you only see the symbology of the copy. This method also works well for the print layout legend.

Comment: it doesn't work for me (QGIS 3.10). My original layer is composed by 2 symbology group, that are defined by rules. When I collapse the orginal into the copy, then the orignal layer's size get the "normal" size for 1second and then get back the huge size :-(

Comment: And then.... I've deleted the original (buggy) layer -> I've duplicated (again) the 1rst duplicated layer -> write back the wedge_buffer formula.. and now your workaround works !!!! thanks so much

Comment: In fact, it doesn't "stay" at the good size.. after any refresh the huge size get back :(

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse the original into the copy"? My suggestion is to have two separate layers. One layer has the wedge buffer symbology you see on the map. The other layer has a different symbology that looks similar in the legend, but at a smaller size. Don't display the second layer on the map - it's only for the legend.

Comment: ok now, I undestand ! thanks !